# jmx- annotated RouteBuilder not showing up in JConsole

Tags: apache-camel, jmx, spring-jmx

I tried to annotate a RouteBuilder with @ManagedResource and a method from it with @ManagedOperation but i can't find it in JConsole. The other classes including my annotated custom endpoint is showing up fine.

I am not sure if these annotations work with all kinds of classes within camel?! In my case the annotated RouteBuilder is some kind of central control class. Is does not contain a route but is loading several other RouteBuilders. It also adds global (context scope) exception handlers and adds a RoutePolicyFactory that centrally handles start up and control logic.

The methods i want to make available via JMX re method that start/stop certain groups of routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for sake of completeness i add the answer [i got an camel mailing list](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/jmx-annotated-RouteBuilder-not-showing-up-in-JConsole-td5760486.html):

You have to simple implement Service or StaticService (for Singleton Services) and add it to CamelContext via addService.